# Java Dispatching-Runtime type

Tags: java, dispatch, runtime-type

I am confused with method dispatching in java. Why does the first method "a.m1(b)" call  to the class A?

The calling variable is a. And its runtime type is B, isn't it?

```
class A {
    public void m1(A a){
        System.out.println("A-m1");
    }
    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("A-m1");
    }

}
class B extends A {
    public void m1( B b){
        System.out.println("B-m1");

    }
    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("B-m1");

    }

}
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    B b = new B();  
    A a = new B();

        a.m1(b);//prints A-m1
        a.m1();//prints B-m1

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Overload* resolution is done based on compile-time types. A variable of type `A` only exposes the methods `m1()` and `m1(A)`. Because you pass in a parameter, `m1(A)` is invoked; or rather, the appropriate *override* thereof. Except that `m1(B)` is **not** an *override* of `m1(A)`. (Off the top of my head, I don't know if overrides can widen argument signatures, but they certainly can't narrow them.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I didn't really understand why not. For instance, "ast1.collideWith(sp)" on http://java-x.blogspot.de/2006/05/double-dispatch-in-java.html doesn't really use the overload resolution to my understanding because although Asteroid also has collideWith(Spaceship), it goes with that of ExplodingAsteroid. Could you please explain that?

Comment: @Sammy Your situation isn't analogous to that of the example you linked to. `collideWith(SpaceShip)` and `collideWith(GiantSpaceShip)` are resolved just fine at compile-time because when they're called, `this` is always of the enclosing class type - when in you're case, you're deliberately making the compile-time type of `a` be `A`. The overriding methods also override their respective overload in the superclass, instead of overloading a different method signature. (I'm not sure about the exact rules for how the compiler resolves this sort ambiguity.)

Comment: @Sammy Or, to put this differently, there's two steps that happen: **1.** The *overload* is determined using the compile-time types of the receiver *and* the parameters. **2.** The *override* is determined using the runtime type of the receiver. The difference is in step 2. In your case, the method `A.m1(A)` isn't overridden in `B` at all. In the asteroid/spaceship example you linked to, `Asteroid.collideWith(Spaceship)` is overridden by `ExplodingAsteroid.collideWith(Spaceship)` (the signature is the same), so if the receiver type at runtime is `ExplodingAsteroid`, the override is called.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I think I got this. But are there cases where the type of the receiver and the parameters are decided at different times.(i.e. compile type of the receiver & runtime type of the parameters)

Comment: @Sammy Not in Java as far as I know. (Ignoring things like `invokedynamic`.) In C++ methods may be nonvirtual and thus may be resolved at compile-time, and Common Lisp supports *multiple dispatch* where method overrides are determined using the runtime type of all parameters (i.e. the receiver isn't "special" compared to the other parameters.)